# my regex isn't working +/- 99,99

Tags: php, regex

I've tried to write a regex, allowed are only this values:
+ or - at first char then 2 digits then a comma (,) and then 2 digits.
Here's my regex:

```
^(+/-)[0-9]{2}[,][0-9]{2}
```

Maybe someone can help me to fix my regex or tell me what's false.

Thanks

Regards

Comment: You should use a pipe `|` to express an `or` statement. So `(+|-)` would be correct. But you could just use `[+-]` instead. Otherwise, why don't you just use php without regex ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$pattern = "/^[+-][0-9]{2},[0-9]{2}$/";
preg_match($pattern, "-99,99");     // returns 1
preg_match($pattern, "-99,99test"); // returns 0
preg_match($pattern, "+10,20");     // returns 1
preg_match($pattern, "99,99");      // returns 0
preg_match($pattern, "+00,99");     // returns 1
preg_match($pattern, "-9999");      // returns 0
```

Comment: will happily match `+00,00FOO`

Comment: @Kaii Yes, you can append anything after the match. I assume that's what OP wants since he doesn't use the ending delimiter `$`.

Comment: i guess the OP struggles with RegEx, this is why he asked his question here. he clearly states: `allowed are only this values: + or - at first char then 2 digits then a comma (,) and then 2 digits`

Comment: The explanation seems a little vague, but I can add the `$` if it satisfies you. :)

Comment: well, my example was a bit off .. without `$` it would also match `+99,999999`, which is clearly not intended.

Answer (score 1):

The problems with your regex is how you are referencing the plus or minus sign and also that you are not defining the end of the string. You should use something like this:

```
^[+-][0-9]{2},[0-9]{2}$
```

Note that the difference is that I placed those two characters within square brackets. This creates a character class consisting of only one character or the other. I also added the `$` character at the end to indicate the end of the string.

You were using normal brackets - this is a capture group in order to extract the matched text. If I understand your question correctly, you are not looking to extract any text - only to match a certain condition.

I also removed the square brackets from the comma symbol - we need to match only that one character so you can just put a literal comma character.

Comment: I'd really like to improve my regex skills - so a comment explaining why you think this answer is bad would be really helpful to me.

Comment: this works for the example, but actually `[+|-]` means: `+` or `|` or `-`, which was not your intent. `[+-]` will create a character class consisting of one character or the other. the `|` separator (boolean OR) only exists in matches inside round brackets (`(one|two)`)

Comment: @Kaii - So if I remove that pipe character I'll still have a character class that will only match those two characters?

Comment: @Kaii - yes. That is the tutorial I'm going by.

Comment: @Kaii - really appreciate your assistance here! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression

```
preg_match("/^(\+|-)[0-9]{2}[,][0-9]{2}$/","+99,09");
```